# MATLAB chart title show equation base properly

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to show the chemical equation for PLA properly in my title.  I've tried the following code but it isn't visualizing properly.

```
% CaP Scaffold     
y = [2.16E+11 2.34E+11 4.22E+10 ;1.24E+11 1.77E+11 1.36E+11;2.24E+11 7.12E+11 9.37E+10];    
bar(y)
title ('Calcium Phosphate [ Ca{3}(PO{4}){2} ] ')
```

How can I get the base of each compound to show properly?

Comment: you may want to explain what wyould you expect as proper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the underscore symbol for subscripts.  You also may want to group each chemical compound with a pair of `{}` symbols too to make it look nice.

Therefore:

```
y = [2.16E+11 2.34E+11 4.22E+10 ;1.24E+11 1.77E+11 1.36E+11;2.24E+11 7.12E+11 9.37E+10];

bar(y)

title('Calcium Phosphate [{Ca}_{3}(PO_{4})_{2}]'); %// Change
```

We get:

[image]